# code If number greater than x, make y = amount

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a iOS app which calculates annualized income and 401(k) contribution.  I can't figure out how to code the func so it limits the 401(k) contribution at 18500 despite the percentage of income put in by the employee.  I know this is super basic but I've been working on it for hours and I can't seem to get it to work.  Any help is appreciated.

```
func your401 () -> int {
    if employee401kContribution < 18500 {
        return employee401kContribution
    }
    else do {return = 18500 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close! You just have a few small isuess:

1. You don't put an equals sign after `return`. It's a special form, and it doesn't use the equals sign. Just `return 18500` (or you could even style it as `return 18_500`).
2. You don't put `do` after `else`. Just `if { ... } else { ... }`
3. The return type is `int`, but the data type you're looking for is `Int`. Identifiers, such as type and variable names, are case sensative.
4. `your401` is not a descriptive name. You should name this function to more clearly communicate exactly what it does.

Here's what you get if you fix it up:

```
func nameMeBetter() -> Int {
   if employee401kContribution < 18_500 {
       return employee401kContribution
   } else {
       return 18_500
   }
}
```

Even simpler, you can implement this with [`Swift.min(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1538339-min):

```
func nameMeBetter() -> Int {
   return min(employee401kContribution, 18_500)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a few ways

```
// Closest to your original code
func your401() -> Int {
    if employee401kContribution < 18500 {
        return employee401kContribution
    } else {
        return 18500
    }
}

// A shorter version using the conditional ternary operator
// return (condition) ? (value if true) : (value if false)
func your401() -> Int {
    return employee401kContribution < 18500 ? employee401kContribution : 18500
}

// Most compact of all. This stays close to the English description
// "the employee's 401k contribution or 18500, whichever is less"
func your401() -> Int {
    return min(employee401kContribution, 18500)
}
```